# Multiple series values for column chart does not align with Category Labels

Tags: date, reporting-services, charts, format, label

I am creating column chart with NimbusId as Value, Month as Category, Status as Series.
Purpose: To find Nimbus# status for each month. Data is all working fine.
Issue: If there is no status count available for some month then label is X axis label does not align with the bar as in below link. I have set the Interval to Auto but it didn't help.
What setting should I do to make it work so that it aligns with each month properly.

Please use the Link http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2572elw&s=8#.U5eiL_ldV4A for the image as I cannot paste Image. Any Help is appreciated

Thank You

Comment: It looks correct to me.  It looks like you have 3 status values so there can be 3 columns for each Month, which would appear side-by-side.

Comment: Yup, I disabled zero values which was not making sense, so I enabled it again so that chart is readable. Do you know how to pop color for zero values in the chart?

Comment: Look in the series Properties for the EmptyPoint section.